# How can I merge several .opml files?

Tags: rss, feed-reader

I've three different sets of blog lists on 3 different PC's. How can I merge them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to just edit the text of the OMPL files. They're human-readable XML feeds. Take all of the `<outline>` elements from the `<body>` block and combine them into one big body block in one of the three files. Your RSS reader should handle any duplicates that result.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool called [**OPML Merge**](http://sharedvalues.sourceforge.net/opml/) which should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

XML Notepad by microsoft. Or just notepad++.

Just be careful about the start and end tags.

Comment: A little more information would be helpfull.